# RetainCycle Memory leak with AppleScriptObject in NSBlockOperation

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, applescript, retain-cycle

I'm on X-Code 8.2, OSX not iOS, Objective-C

In a custom NSBlockOperation I included an Applescript (gets compiled by XCode) like that:

SHImportLayoutOperation.m file

```
#import "SHImportLayoutOperation.h"
#import "Helpers.h"

@class SHIndesignImport; // Applescript

// ################################################
@interface SHImportLayoutOperation()

@property SHIndesignImport *indesignImport;

@end

// ################################################
@interface SHIndesignImport:NSObject

// Methods
- (NSMutableDictionary*)scanIndesign:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters errors:(NSMutableArray*)errors;
@property NSBlockOperation* operation;

@end


// ################################################
@implementation SHImportLayoutOperation

    - (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _helpers = [[Helpers alloc] init];
        init];
        _indesignImport = [[NSClassFromString(@"SHIndesignImport") alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Later on in the operation i need a method of the script. Everything just works fine. BUT: i want to pass a reference of the current operation (self) to the script to check for the isCancelled state. This also works but leads to a memory leak/cycle.

```
[_indesignImport setOperation:self];

// call scanIndesign
NSMutableDictionary* scanIndesignResult = [_indesignImport scanIndesign:parametersINDD errors:errors];
_indesignImport.operation = nil;
```

This leads to the cycle. So i tried a weak self

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[_indesignImport setOperation:weakSelf];

// call scanIndesign
NSMutableDictionary* scanIndesignResult = [_indesignImport scanIndesign:parametersINDD errors:errors];
_indesignImport.operation = nil;
```

Same error. Then i tried to release it from within the applescript (at the end):

```
-- Beginning of script
@property operation: missing value

-- Lots of stuff --

-- End of script
set operation to missing value
```

Same stuff. If i don't pass the reference everything works fine. No cycle. So this has to be the reason. Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here's a screenshot of instruments. As you can see, the ref count is still 1 (this is with the weakSelf)

[image: As you can see, the ref count is still 1 (this is with the weakSelf)]

Comment: So a `SHImportLayoutOperation` retains a `SHIndesignImport` and that retains an `NSBlockOperation`, which you are setting to `self`, which is an instance of `SHImportLayoutOperation`.  That's a cycle.  The weak copy you set ought to solve the problem, but the question says "Same problem" without elaborating on any evidence for that.  How are you deciding that a cycle exists, and that you have a problem?

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out more clearly. What I can say is that no matter what I tried the operation is (after finishing) not removed from memory. Just if I don't pass the reference it's removed. Maybe it's something to do with the scripting bridge

Comment: Could you explain more about "not removed from memory"?  It's okay to be in memory so long as the retain count goes to 0.  Have you checked it's retain count, or do you mean it's dealloc isn't invoked?

Comment: Retain count stays at 1. Edited post - check the screenshot.